# Entity framework navigational property as table too?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

I'm using database first in EF6, let's say I have a table called `Article` with (`ArticleID`, `title`, `text`)
with the `articleID` as the primary key.

Then I add a table called `RelatedArticle` that has (`ArticleID`, `RelatedArticleID`), the primary key is both the articleid and the relatedarticleid with foreign keys back to the article for both.

The problem I'm having is when I pull it into the edmx file it *only* sets `RelatedArticles` as a navigation property off of an article so when I go to delete, it only pulls the `relatedarticles` where the `articleid` is the article's `id` I'm trying to delete. Well as you can imagine, I need to be able to say

> delete any records where the articleid OR the related articleid is the current article's id that I'm trying to delete.

Or I get big ole FK constraint errors.

Typically when this happens I at least have a "table" off of the context that I can just query manually and kill what I need to. (for example:

```
context.RelatedArticles.Where(ra => ra.ArticleID == articleID OR 
                              ra.RelatedArticleID == articleID)
```

But like I said it only pulls in the related articles as a navigational property off of the Article itself.

Ideas?

Comment: Is the table showing up as an option for import when you update the edmx file from the designer?

Comment: The table shows up as an option to pull into the edmx file, yes, but it only adds it as a navigational property off of the Article entity. It doesn't give me an entity type of "RelatedArticles" off the context.

Comment: From my recollection, the edmx file will only pull in the table and put it on the context if you tell it to. I think it's quite content to leave it out otherwise.

Comment: Try deleting surrogate key from RelatedArticle, add new column ID autoincrement for example and make it primary key. ArticleID, RelatedArticleID foreign key leave as they are.